# Showing initial v-model value on selectbox

Tags: vue.js

I have a selectbox in vue that has initial v-model value and i want to show its value on the selectbox but actually i do not know how to do it .
i would really appreaciate if someone can help

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
    newRecordDurationName: '2min',
           recordDuration: [
        { id: 1, name: "2 min" },
        { id: 2, name: "5 min" },
        { id: 3, name: "10 min" },
        { id: 4, name: "15 min" },
        { id: 5, name: "30 min" },

      ],
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="container">

<select
              v-model="newRecordDurationName"
              class="w-75 mr-auto text-dark radius-8 py-2"
              name=""
              id=""
            >
              <option
                v-for="type in recordDuration"
                :key="type.id"
                :value="type.id"
              >
                {{ type.name }}
              </option>
            </select>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `id` of the required value to your `v-model` (newRecordDurationName) not the `name`. check the below update code.
So if you want '2min' to be the default value then set 1, if you want '10 min' as default value then set `v-model` to 3,.. like that

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
    newRecordDurationName: 1,
           recordDuration: [
        { id: 1, name: "2 min" },
        { id: 2, name: "5 min" },
        { id: 3, name: "10 min" },
        { id: 4, name: "15 min" },
        { id: 5, name: "30 min" },

      ],
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="container">

<select
              v-model="newRecordDurationName"
              class="w-75 mr-auto text-dark radius-8 py-2"
              name=""
              id=""
            >
              <option
                v-for="type in recordDuration"
                :key="type.id"
                :value="type.id"
              >
                {{ type.name }}
              </option>
            </select>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a mistake that i am setting id and showing data
if i give an id to v-model it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).